# How to design good plots for multiple time series?

Tags: time-series, data-visualization

I have huge (about 100 000) set of time series. I need to show between 5 to 10 time series, chosen semi-randomly on one chart. Chart estate is very limited - plot for each time series is only 100px x 800px.

It is not possible o predict which time series will be shown together - they have to be plot independently.

Ranges of all variables are very different: for one time series it can be between 0-3000 and for another 0 to 50. General range of all variables is 0-60000.

I want to use horizon graphs: http://timelyportfolio.blogspot.com/2012/08/more-on-horizon-charts.html but, if I make plots using 4 bands almost all time series will look flat. If I plot using 32 bands - plots will change from horizon charts, to heatmap charts.

Is it good idea, to set bands range not uniform? i.e. 1st band: 0-100, 2nd: 100-1000 3rd: 1000-5000, 4th: 5000-60000.

Comment: Good question - including from a stats/visualisations view, not just programming - but I'll be interested if anyone can help - it looks like a workable solution will be very much dependent on your actual data and getting it to work within the chart estate.

Comment: I've never used, nor encountered, horizon graphs in a "real" environment, so I don't have much experience to draw from.  That said, if you can't find a uniform scale for the banding, I would try a log-scale for the band values, if for no other reason than the varied scales will match what the viewers have likely encountered in other charts giving them a better frame of reference for reading your chart.